# Download file through FTP by Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming, quartz-scheduler

I tried working Ftp download stand alone application and it works fine. But when I included that into Quartz scheduler in web application, it stucks.

Here is what I did.

```
public class FtpTransfer implements StatefulJob {
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream br = null;
    try
    {
        ftp.connect("localhost");
        ftp.login("admin", "admin");
        String path = "alfresco/MYPUB/Admin/TMM/Pickup";
        ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(path);
        System.out.println("After Changing Directory path");
        FTPFile[] ftpFile =  ftp.listFiles(path);
        System.out.println("After getting list of files");
        System.out.println("Length : "+ftpFile.length);
        System.out.println("----------------- Downloaded -------------");
        for(FTPFile tempFtpFiles : ftpFile) {
            br = new FileOutputStream("e:\\Downloaded\\"+tempFtpFiles.getName());
            ftp.retrieveFile(tempFtpFiles.getName(), br);
            System.out.println(tempFtpFiles.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

    }
    catch(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Error : "+exception);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(br!=null){
                br.close();
            }
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error : "+e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I start the server, It prints

```
After Changing Directory path
After Changing Directory path
After Changing Directory path
```

Every 10 secs. But It is not downloading the files from the path given. Mailnly the program didn't crossed the line FTPFile[] ftpFile =  ftp.listFiles(path). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check whether you have to use active or passive ftp, if a firewall/net gateway is blocking active FTP, you'll simply block and perhaps eventually time out - switching to passive FTP usually works around that.

Comment: Agree with nos, check whether the following FTPClient methods help you try that out: http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I have found the problem. After included **jakarta-oro.jar** in lib, its working fine.